# What is the starting wealth/equipment for characters?

Tags: dragon-age-rpg

Despite reading through things now the fifth time I did not find anything there. So is there any infos what characters start with equipment and wealth wise?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the first Dragon Age Boxed set, it's on page 30 of the Player's Guide. In the Dragon Age Core Rulebook, it's on page 40. In both cases the text appears the same. In the section titled "Equipment," it says:

> Characters begin play with the following:
>
> - A backpack.
> - Traveler’s garb.
> - A waterskin.
> - If you are a mage, you get one weapon and a wand (for your arcane lance).
> - If you are a rogue, you get light leather armor and two weapons.
> - If you are a warrior, you get heavy leather armor and three weapons.
> - If you choose a bow or crossbow, you get a quiver and 20 arrows or bolts.
> - If you have the Weapon and Shield talent, you get a medium shield.

It also says on the same page:

> Your character also gets 50 + 3d6 silver Pieces to buy additional
>   gear.

Comment: Both answers are correct thus upvoted (overlooked it first in the core rulebook and then also in the other one.....no comment there). Both answers upvoted. As both are correct I will set the earlier answer as finishing one, but in reality both are equally correct imho.

Comment: Added the info about the core rulebook to my answer, just so they're both there.

Comment: Okay, why the sudden downvote for improving the answer?

Comment: no clue wasn't me

Answer (score 4):

From the **Equipment** topic on the **Character Creation** chapter of the **Dragon Age Core Rulebook** (page 40):

Characters begin play with the following:

- A backpack, traveler’s garb, and a waterskin.
- If you are a mage, you get one weapon and a staff (for
  your Arcane Lance).
- If you are a rogue, you get light leather armor and two
  weapons.
- If you are a warrior, you get heavy leather armor and
  three weapons.
- If you choose a bow or crossbow, you get a quiver and
  20 arrows or bolts.
- If you have the Weapon and Shield talent, you get a
  medium shield.

Your character also gets **50 + 3d6 silver pieces** to buy additional
gear. You’ll find a complete list of available items in
Chapter 4: Weapons, Armor, & Gear.

Comment: Both answers are correct thus upvoted (overlooked it first in the core rulebook and then also in the other one.....no comment there). Both answers upvoted. As both are correct I will set the earlier answer as finishing one, but in reality both are equally correct imho.